# dividing a number by a string that contains a value?

Tags: python, string, integer, operators

I define, let's say, `E=10` the I try to do `A=1/E` (in python), then python tells me :

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'`

How should I do this please?

Thanks !

Comment: Hint: You need to convert the `str` into an `int`/`float`.

Comment: Are you using `input` to get `E`?  If so, you need to use `int` to make it an integer before you can  use it in a numeric context.  `E = int(input())`

Comment: This shouldn't happen if you define `E = 10`. It would only happen if you define `E = "10"`. `10` is an `int`, `"10"` is a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> E=10.0
>>> A=1/E
>>> print(A)
```

0.1

Comment: Thanks for your answers, the problem was that I defined it as `E=10,` I shouldn't have put ',' at the end!

Comment: There is another problem now: I have E=5000 and 1/E gives 0, why is that?

Comment: See my answer carefully. You must define E=5000 as **E=5000.0** E must be float and not integer